# How to insert empty rows and let data start on certain row number?

Tags: pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I am completely new in coding and started to experiment with python and pandas. Quite an adventure and I am learning a lot. I found a lot of solutions already here on Stack, but not for my latest quest.

With Pandas I imported and edited a txt-file in such a way that I could export it in a csv-file. But to be able to import this csv-file into another program I need that the header row starts on row number 20. So I actually need 19 empty rows.

Can somebody guide me in the right direction?

Comment: never heard about a program which reads only from row20 on :0 but why you just adding 19 "carriage return" to your file before progressing with your usual stuff ?

Comment: Please can you be more specific in what your trying to achieve. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join your dataframe with an empty dataframe:

```
empty_data = [[''] * len(df.columns) for i in range(19)]
empty_df = pd.DataFrame(empty_data, columns=df.columns)
pd.concat((df, empty_df))
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Sorry for not being clear enough. I'll try better next time